# How can I change a value inside of a function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, click

I have just started creating my own little clicker game and I am stuck at a dead end. I have a click count and I want to create a button that changes the number that the count increases by.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Rust Clicker </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

        <link rel="icon" src="icon.ico">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div onClick="onClick()">

            <img src="rust.jpg" id="click" value="Click" />

        </div>

        <script src="picture.js"></script>

        <script src="clicks.js"></script>

            <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

            <button onClick="">Click me to click twice!</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Towards the bottom of the html I have a button that I want to alter the value that the click count goes up by in my clicks.js file. Below is the clicks.js:

```
var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

I want to make the button in my HTML to increase the "clicks += 1;" to "clicks +=2" but don't know how to.

Comment: Inside `onClick()` you are in another scope than outside. `clicks` is `undefined` inside the scope of `onClick()`. Solution: make `clicks` global by adding it to (for example) the `window` object.

Comment: @Koen `clicks`is already global. It is defined outside of the function. And this has nothing to do wiith OPs question.

Comment: `I want to make the button in my HTML increase the "clicks += 1;" to "clicks +=2"` if i understand this correctly you want to add 2 to the click var, you can achieve this by setting a global variable `clicksIncrement = 1` and replace the `clicks += 1;` with `clicks += clickIncrement` and somewhere you would need to increment the `clickincrement` var.

Comment: also i suggest using `<span>` instead of `<a>` to show the clicks.  and you need to call the `onClick()` function like this: `<button onClick="twoClicksFunction(); onClick()">Click me to click twice!</button>` where `twoClickFunction()` would be the function to set increment to 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want the click event to change the function itself?

If so, I am not too sure that is something that could be done. I could be wrong, since I am still just starting like you. :)

If the change caused by a click is specific to the element that is clicked, you could possibly do the following:

```
var clicks = 0;

function onClick(x) {
  clicks += x;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

Then for your button you can do:

```
<button onClick="onClick(2)">Click me to click twice!</button>
```

...and elsewhere, for example:

```
<div onClick="onClick(1)">

    <img src="rust.jpg" id="click" value="Click" />

</div>
```

For one click and so on.

Hope this helps in some way :)